Practical applications of dynamic fund protection?
I am reading the paper 'Pricing Dynamic Investment Fund Protection', by Gerber and Pafumi (2000), where Dynamic Fund Protection (DFP) is defined as
$\tilde{F}(t)=F(t) \max \left\{1, \max _{0 \leq \mathrm{s} \leq t} K / F(s)\right\}$. Are there any similar real-world applications?
